# Expandable List View Change the Paren Value By Clicking the Child?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I want to make a Explandablelistview  Which will Extand an Activity ...and the Value of the Parent Should be Changed according to the clicking of child ...Any Suggestion or Tutorial

```
PARENT
  Child 1
  Child 2    <--- this value will be  clicked.
  Child 3
```

When Click on child on Any Child I want to Rename the Parent to --- > Clicked Child.

Like

```
Child 2
  Child 1
  Child 2    <--- this value was clicked.
  Child 3
```

I want some sort of tutorial ............

Comment: 1) Get parent item 2) Update paret item 3) adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: did you got the solution for the same? I also want the same stuff. Could you help me for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `OnChildClickListener` and override `onChildClick()`. This will give you the `groupPosition` that child belongs to. Knowing the position of the parent, as Georgy said in comments, you could update that item and then notify the adapter that the data set has changed.